# Create a VHD from a physical XP machine

Tags: windows-xp, windows-7, virtualization, vhd

I am looking at upgrading from Windows XP to Windows7.  I have a lot of development programs that would take 2-3 days to set-up configure etc. etc. when I get my new machine.  What I want to do is create a VHD of my physical XP machine install Windows 7 and then operate out of my Virtual PC while I take the time to configure Windows 7.  Is this possible to do?  If so how do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use VMWare converter and VMware server. Both of which are free.

Comment: Could I use Virtual PC with the image created by VMWare converter?

Comment: No, but if you NEED to use Virtual PC follow these steps http://support.microsoft.com/kb/912826

Answer (score 2):

You should use the *free* [Disk2VHD tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx) which will create a VHD from a disk, even if currently running. It also neatens up the device listings so the VHD will boot correctly under VirtualPC/Hyper-V/Windows Virtual

This tool was written by Mark Russinovich and the gang at SysInternals. It runs perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an easy way to do it. I don't have direct experice with the VM capibilities of Windows 7 (yet, no time to try it out), but the long way around it would be to convert physical to VMWare HD, then use a tool to convert to Virtual PC. 
http://vmtoolkit.com/files/folders/converters/entry8.aspx

Not very clean, but could work.

The other way that might work is to use an imaging program like Acronis to image the drive, then in Windows 7, create a new VHD, restore your image to that VHD. 
http:/ /www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/566-virtual-hard-disk-create-attach-vhd.html

Just thoughts, haven't tested it out or anything.

Good luck!

Comment: I tried the vmtoolkit tool and could not boot the VHD image that it created.